# Get notified when QQuickItem will need updating

Tags: qt

I have search high and low in the documentation but have  not found anything regarding this. Is there anyway that an QML  element I have created can get notified if one of it's children needs to be redrawn due to changes to it. Will the item send a signal or an event that the parent can connect/listen to. Preferably it would be emitted when the item is marked "dirty" and should be rendered again, but a signal like onPropertyChange would work also.

Example

```
 MyQmlItem {
     Rectangle {
          width: 50; height: 60
          color: "blue"
          Text {
              text: "hello world"
          }
     }
}
```

If some code e.g changes the color of the Rectangle I would like the MyQmlItem to be notified about this change.

Comment: Can you elaborate about *why* would you need such a thing?

Comment: I am rendering these items into a QOpenGLFramebufferObject which i then grab as an image and write to offscreen device. I want to avoid this write if nothing is updated

Comment: The writing will happen every other Qt render frame regardless if the FBO needs redrawing

Answer (score 0):

FWIIW i managed to find an acceptable solution to above. I added a boolean property "isDirty" to the MyQmlItem class, this emits a signal when it is set to true. Then each child needs to set this if it makes changes that needs redrawing, the QML above then becomes

```
MyQmlItem {
   id: "topItem"
   Rectangle {
      width: 50; height: 60
      color: "blue"
      Text {
          text: "hello world"
          onTextChange: {
              topItem.isDirty = true;
          }
      }
 }
```

not perfect, but good enough