# Can I be notified when a Item has finished repainting?

Tags: qt, events, qml, qtquick2, repaint

I'm making a snapshot (via a `ShaderEffectSource` with `live: false`) of an Item, but I'm sometimes (1 cases in 200) getting a blank snapshot. I'm making the snapshot based on a signal like this:

```
Image {
    onStatusChanged: {
        if (status == Image.Ready) {
            snapshotter.makeSnapshot();
        }
    }
}
```

This is just as an overall context. I won't post a testcase for now because it's a big app and I haven't yet isolated a testcase. That might be material for a future question.

So I'm not asking "where's the bug in my code" yet. Instead I have a simple question that I think may help me fix the bug:

**Can I be notified when a Item has finished repainting?**

Rationale: Maybe when I get `status == Image.Ready`, the Image has merely **loaded** and not yet painted the loaded data into the offscreen surface. So if my desired signal exists, I could hook onto **it** instead of hooking onto `Image.statusChanged`.

**Note:** I could implement my own `NotifyingImage` component that works like `Image` but additionally exposes a `repainted` signal. But I'd like to know if there's a built-in way.

**Related question:** "[Get notified when QQuickItem will need updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024366/get-notified-when-qquickitem-will-need-updating)". But there the asker is satisfied with knowing when the item *data* is updated, and I'm asking about a `repainted` signal, which is something that happens *later* than what he's asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know a `Window` is always renderd as a whole. So you might use the `Window`'s [`afterRendering`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#afterRendering) signal.

The downside: It will be triggered, when ever anything in the window has changed. But combined with the `(status == Image.Ready)` it might work for you.

**EDIT:**
In a [blog post, announcing the release of `Qt5.8`](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/01/23/qt-5-8-released/) the *Qt Companies CTO* wrote:

> In addition, the scene graph now supports **partial updates** to the screen if only a small area of the scenography changed. This brings some larger performance improvements to the Qt Quick 2D renderer.

I don't know the implementation details of the signal `afterRendering`, so I can't tell whether this is triggered after such a *partial update* and if so, how to tell, whether that partial update concerned that part, you are interested in.