# How to get notified when a QQuickItem is updated?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a qml window which displays different modules. It displays details like time, playing media etc.. I am trying to get a notification when any one module screen is updated.

I know there is `QQuickWindow::afterRendering()` for `Window`, but not found anything similar for `QQuickItem`.

Is there anyway to achieve similar notification for `QQuickItem`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I be notified when a Item has finished repainting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479213/can-i-be-notified-when-a-item-has-finished-repainting)

Comment: @derM: So what i can do is use separate windows only to get separate notifications for each module..? :(

Comment: What is your usecase?

Comment: @derM: i have a one deivce only for display and the other one where application really runs. I have split the application window to different module spaces, and needs to send only the one window area which gets updated to the display device. So to select the area of main Window, I need QQuickItem's dirty call.

Comment: Sry, I can't follow you. What *'needs to send only the one window area'*? I have no clue what you try to achive.

Comment: I have one `window`, in which I have 3 `Item`s. Each `Item` is the display of my each modules. What I try to achieve is that, whenever there is an update to any one of the modules (or any of the `Item`), I need to take a screen shot of that particular `Item`. Hope I made it clear...

Comment: Is there any reason, why that change would not happen only after some of it's data changed? Just crawl your modules, connect to each `xxxChanged`-handler, to mark it dirty, and screenshot it, when the next `afterRendering` occured.

Comment: @derM: you mean to say keep the possibly changed modules list and on `afterRendering` is occured for `window` grab the changed module screens screenshot. right? But that would be so hard to do, say if I have a temperature display and time display in one module, I need to invoked the `xxxChanged` handler in both updates. And for my case there are several aspects why a screen may be dirty. To handle all separately looks so hard.